# One Service with variable in many ngModule

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-modules

It's not really a problem but it's a question :

In a test project, I try to use ng2-translate in multiple ngModule with a same TranslateService.

**package.json :**

```
"ng2-translate": "^4.0.0"
```

It's not working, for every module I must to declare a new

'TranslateModule'

And in components, it's a new TranslateService so it's does not keep translate language value.

Have you trying to inject same service in multiple ngModule ? if yes, how ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#installation](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#installation) installation notes? It clearly states how to use this module for all classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shared module

```
   import {TranslateModule, TranslateService, TranslateLoader,    TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
    @NgModule({
        imports: [..,TranslateModule],
        declarations: [..],
        exports: [ .., TranslateModule]
    })
    export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {

       function translateLoader(http: Http) {
            return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'i18n', '.json');
        }
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [UserService, ItemService, {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: translateLoader,
                deps: [Http]
            },
                TranslateService],
        };
    }
    }
```

Change TranslateModule.forRoot() in AppModule.ts to SharedModule.forRoot().

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987013/ng2-translate-not-working-in-lazy-loaded-module)

Comment: it's work, but I just modify this line :

`import {TranslateModule, TranslateService, TranslateLoader,    TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';`

by 

 `import {TranslateModule, TranslateService, TranslateLoader,    TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate';`