# i18n of lazy-loaded components in JHipster app

Tags: angular, jhipster, ngx-translate

[My App](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/dashboard/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts#L55) is based on [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io) and so the language services are provided by way of [JhiLanguageService](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/0f20f41153369fcd35525db23b66ebd3aaed64b8/src/language/language.service.ts#L29) in the `ng-jhipster` library which uses a [JhiConfigService](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/0f20f41153369fcd35525db23b66ebd3aaed64b8/src/config.service.ts) to configure `ngx-translate` without my needing to import and configure the TranslateModule in my `app.module`. So when I add `TranslateModule.forRoot(...)` to imports of AppModule, everything breaks and I just see "translation not found..." messages everywhere.

I don't know how to make my lazy-loaded pages use the same translation service instance as the eager-loaded part of the app so that changing the language in an eagerly-loaded component of the nav bar affects the language used by the lazy-loaded pages.

I have looked into [this idea](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues/1079#issuecomment-301707767) and [this idea](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/232#issuecomment-281455131) but they both prescribe configuring TranslateModule in AppModule which breaks it and I don't know how to control ngx-translate configuration in a JHipster app.

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987013/ng2-translate-not-working-in-lazy-loaded-module

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try too, but no luck. Apparently lazy loading modules is a known problem with JHipster Angular apps and they plan to address it in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix translation in my lazy loaded module by adding BehaviorSubject to the JhiLanguageHelper service.

```
@Injectable()
export class JhiLanguageHelper {
    renderer: Renderer2 = null;
    private _language: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    constructor(
        private translateService: TranslateService,
        private rootRenderer: RendererFactory2,
        private findLanguageFromKeyPipe: FindLanguageFromKeyPipe,
        private titleService: Title,
        private router: Router
    ) {
        this._language = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.translateService.currentLang);
        this.renderer = rootRenderer.createRenderer(document.querySelector('html'), null);
        this.init();
    }

    getAll(): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.resolve(LANGUAGES);
    }

    get language(): Observable<string> {
        return this._language.asObservable();
    }

    updateTitle(titleKey?: string) {
        if (!titleKey) {
             titleKey = this.getPageTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root);
        }

        this.translateService.get(titleKey).subscribe((title) => {
            this.titleService.setTitle(title);
        });
    }

    private init() {
        this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
            this._language.next(this.translateService.currentLang);
            this.renderer.setAttribute(document.querySelector('html'), 'lang', this.translateService.currentLang);
            this.updateTitle();
            this.updatePageDirection();
        });
    }

    private getPageTitle(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let title: string = (routeSnapshot.data && routeSnapshot.data['pageTitle']) ? routeSnapshot.data['pageTitle'] : 'hcmGatewayApp';
        if (routeSnapshot.firstChild) {
            title = this.getPageTitle(routeSnapshot.firstChild) || title;
        }
        return title;
    }

    private updatePageDirection() {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(document.querySelector('html'), 'dir', this.findLanguageFromKeyPipe.isRTL(this.translateService.currentLang) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr');
    }
}
```

And you subscribe to the BehaviorSubject in your module like this.

```
export class YourModule {
    constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService, private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper) {
        this.languageHelper.language.subscribe((languageKey: string) => this.languageService.changeLanguage(languageKey));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code in your question and not as a link.